# www redirect on subfolder (htaccess 301)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a simple 301 redirect but I seem to be missing something

the idea is to redirect `myhost.com/crm/` to `www.myhost.com/crm/`.
So I googled around and came up with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which works perfectly fine in my root (so on myhost.com)
however when placing this in my crm subfolder as follows it fails (in fact it doesn't do anything):

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/crm/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm a bit baffled what I'm doing wrong here. Am I placing the rules in the wrong .htaccess file?

I've tried searching stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer that suited what I need. (as it isn't crm.myhost.com)

Comment: So you want only the folder CRM to be accessible via www.domain and the rest of the site to be accessible via both? www and non www ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/crm/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You want your redirect rule **before** any kind of routing rules:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/crm/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```